# Adding Numbers that are coming from ArrayList

Tags: ios, addition, store

Here is my Problem, I was able to get the `ArrayList` (no of Hours) from `JSON`, The problem is I want to add all the Hours and store the same into a variable so that I can access for next page. Simply saying I want to get the total no of hours from the array. When keeping `NSLog` for Hours I am getting

```
Hours Total : (
    "13.5",
    "12.5"
)
```

I want to add 13.5 + 12.5 and store in a Variable

Comment: get the int value from string and add it, whats problem with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float sum = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"] floatValue];
```

Above will give you float value.

**Assumption:* Time 13.5 means 13 hours and 30 minutes, and not 13 hours 50 minutes.

Comment: Thanks dude you are my Rock Star for the day.. +1 for the exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to add 13.5 and 12.5 and store the result in a variable, what is the problem?

You will have items of type NSNumber* containing numbers, you can extract the values by calling doubleValue, you make a variable of type double, and add the numbers.

Comment: How can I add the two numbers that comes from a single array list

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. i think you are new in iOS Programming. But don't worry we are here to solve your questions.

You have array of Numbers as string in your Array List. Let assume that "HoursTotal" is your array of numbers. Now please follow the below steps:

1. Get the First Object From Array using the this method:

   ```
   NSString *firstObject = [HoursTotal objectAtIndex:0];
   int firstValue = [firstObject intValue];
   ```
2. Same process for getting second value from Object

   ```
   NSString *secondObject = [HoursTotal objectAtIndex:1];
   int secondValue = [secondObject intValue];
   ```

Now you can add the both int value using math operator in objective C.